# How to retrieve Property ID and use utm marks in Google Analytics Data API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to switch from [Google Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4)  to [Google Analytics Data API (GA4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)
.

In **Reporting API** it was possible to retieve all `view id` for account (used to send requests) by special [endpoint](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/). In **Analytics Data API** there is no `view id`, but there is `Property ID` which is used to send requests. But I didn't find any endpoint to get `Property ID` through REST. Is it even possible or it's only available from https://analytics.google.com/ admin panel?

Also in **Reporting API** to send requests I used *utm marks* in `dimensionFilterClauses` array like this:

```
"dimensionFilterClauses":[
      {
         "operator":"AND",
         "filters":[
            {
               "dimensionName":"ga:campaign",
               "operator":"EXACT",
               "expressions":[
                  "some_campaign_name_2021"
               ]
            },
            {
               "dimensionName":"ga:adContent",
               "operator":"EXACT",
               "expressions":[
                  "multiformat"
               ]
            },
            {
               "dimensionName":"ga:medium",
               "operator":"EXACT",
               "expressions":[
                  "cpm"
               ]
            },
            {
               "dimensionName":"ga:source",
               "operator":"EXACT",
               "expressions":[
                  "facebook"
               ]
            },
            {
               "dimensionName":"ga:keyword",
               "operator":"EXACT",
               "expressions":[
                  "car"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
```

How can I do it with **Google Analytics Data API (GA4)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Admin API to list all GA4 Properties that you have access to. The method is [accountSummaries.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/accountSummaries/list).

The response will contain for example...

```
     "propertySummaries": [
        {
          "property": "properties/215...",
          "displayName": "You GA4 Property Name"
        },
      ...
```

For the utm marks, you'll need to translate those dimension names from GA3 to GA4. This [page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/migration-api-schema-mapping) provides the equivalent dimensions in GA4. For example, `ga:source` in GA3 is similar to `source` in GA4. Note that `ga:keyword` and `ga:adContent` are not yet available in GA4.

Comment: Is `dimensionFilter` from G4A equivalent for old `dimensionFilterClauses`?

Comment: Does Google Analytics Admin API (GA4) work with GA GOALS?

Comment: Yes, `dimensionFilter` in GA4 is functionally equivalent to `dimensionFilterClauses`. However, the JSON structure is different.

Comment: Conversions in GA4 are the most similar functionality to Goals in GA3 (UA). The Admin API does not yet support operations on a property's conversions [reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/).